# Start in Source mode when editing .axml Xamarin Android views in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am not sure if this is possible, but is there an option to default to "Source" editing mode when opening Android .axml files via Xamarin in Visual Studio?

My reason is two fold,

1. I always switch to Source and never work on the designer surface.
2. It takes at least 2-3 seconds for the designer surface to "load" which blocks the UI before I can press the Source button.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any fresh information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't an option to do that. If you get a chance to try out the alpha channel, the delay might at least be gone. If not, it might be worth filing a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com.